# Converting Time Output to a Float Variable (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, floating-point

```
from Tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import math

rate1 = str(35.34) 
amp = 2.40
pmp = 2.50



signOnSun1 = raw_input("What time did you sign on Sunday: ");
signOffSun1 = raw_input("What time did you sign off Sunday: ");

if (signOnSun1 < 0600):
    rate1 = rate1 + amp
elif (signOnSun1 > 1100):
    rate1 = rate1 + pmp
elif (signOffSun1 > 1800):
    rate1 = rate1 + pmp
else:
    rate1 = 35.34

FMT = '%H%M'    
timeWorkedSun1 =  ( (datetime.strptime(signOffSun1, FMT)) -  (datetime.strptime   (signOnSun1, FMT)))
```

*** I want to convert timeWorkedSun1 to a float so i can multiply it with rate1 but it seems to be the bane of my life. Any ideas?***

Comment: A float of what? Hours? Seconds? Parts of a day?

Comment: so the output i receive is in the format 00:00:00. which is great. but for example if the format says 8:00:00 i want to be able to multiply that with a float. for example 8:00:00 * 34.45 doesn't work. So I'm basically calculating the hours i work per day and multiplying that with my hourly rate. thats the aim

Answer (score 3):

`timeWorkedSun1` is of type `datetime.timedelta`.  Call its `total_seconds` method to translate it into a number of second (then divide by 3600 to get it in hours-and-fractions).  I.e:

```
time_mul_by_hourly_rate = (timeWorkedSun1.total_seconds() / 3600.0) * rate1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you want to do is ask a user to enter two `hours:minutes` figures, and calculate the hours + fractions of hours between them, then using datetime as you do now, you'd do something like (simplified):

```
signOn = "09:15"
signOff = "15:45"

FMT = "%H:%M"
timeWorkedSun =  datetime.strptime(signOff, FMT) -  datetime.strptime(signOn, FMT)

# timeWorkedSun is now a datetime.timedelta
fractionHours = timeWorkedSun.total_seconds()/60.0/60
```

Alternately, without datetime code, we could do:

```
signOn = "09:15"
signOff = "15:45"

signOnP = [int(n) for n in signOn.split(":")]
signOffP = [int(n) for n in signOff.split(":")]

signOnH = signOnP[0] + signOnP[1]/60.0
signOffH = signOffP[0] + signOffP[1]/60.0

hours = signOffH - signOnH
```

However, that'll fail if someone started at 6pm on one day and ended at 3am the next day, so you might want to rethink your logic

Comment: 2 big issues: timeWorkedSun.seconds is NOT callable (it's an attribute!) AND it's not the total number of seconds -- try datetime.timedelta(days=1).seconds ...!-). What you need is .total_seconds() as in my answer.  You're right about time shifts passing midnight, though...

Comment: you my friend are a freaked genius!